# Getting responsecode 500 on poset request in android app

Tags: android, http-post

I am trying to implement post request to my android application. But unfortunately I am getting status code 500 in response. Here is my code

```
public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){}

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://serveruri/auth/register"); // here is your URL path

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                postDataParams.put("username", "abcdsdgvsdf");
                postDataParams.put("password", "abcmail");
                postDataParams.put("email", "abc@gmail.com");

                Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("responsecode", String.valueOf(responseCode));

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();

                }
                else {
                    return new String("false : "+responseCode);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I tested the same uri on postman and it is working.

What is the problem here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try my library https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking , it works, Thanks

Comment: What does http error code 500 mean?

Comment: Please show the code of `getPostDataString()` too.

Comment: Please tell which type of server you have.

Comment: What is the difference between `postDataParams.toString()` and `getPostDataString(postDataParams)`?

Comment: try `conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: Please provide the full error message and details on the server. Error 500 is an internal server error that could be diagnosed easily if you provide server details.

Comment: @AmitShekhar I tried your library but getting this error in logcat com.androidnetworking.error.ANError